# Django Haystack Solr: HTTP ERROR 500 accessing /solr/admin/

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

HTTP ERROR 500
 accessing /solr/admin/. Reason: 
    Severe errors in solr configuration.

Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.

If you want solr to continue after configuration errors, change:

false

in solr.xml

---

java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't find resource 'stopwords_en.txt' in classpath or 'solr/./conf/', cwd=/home/bill/solr/boatsite
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.openResource(SolrResourceLoader.java:273)

=========================================================

I am using:

django 1.3.1,   django-haystack 2.0.0beta, JDK1/6/0_31, apache-solr-3.6.0

Directory structure file locations:

```
/home/bill/workspace/boatsite/myapp

/home/bill/solr/boatsite/solr/solr.xml

/home/bill/solr/boatsite/solr/conf/schema.xml

/home/bill/solr/boatsite/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml

/home/bill/solr/boatsite/solr/conf/data/index/*.*
```

NOTE: everything under /solr/ is same as under /example/solr/ in the solr tutorial

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr'
    },
}
```

As far as I can tell every thing below /home/bill/solr/boatsite is identical to /home/bill/solr/example except the schema.xml  java -jar start.jar works for 'example" but not for "boatsite".    What am I missing?

Comment: I'm thinking the problem is in the schema.xml file.  But it was generated by manage.py rebuild_index, and copied unchanged from terminal to file.  I did notice the example file first line is <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> and the one I generated is <?xml version="1.0" ?>, don't know if that would make a difference.

Comment: just changed added the - encoding"UTF-8" - it didn't fix it.

Comment: Do you have `stopwords_en.txt` in the correct place?

Comment: That file is located at /home/bill/sorl/boatsite/conf/lang/stopwords_en.txt, there is also have a stopword.txt file (currently empty) located at /home/bill/sorl/boatsite/conf/

Answer (score 2):

PROBLEM RESOLVED.

Solr 3.6.0 changed where it looks for stopwords_en.txt (now in sub-directory /lang) .  Schema.xml generated by Haystack 2.0.0 beta need to be edited.  Everthing working now.

I think beerbajay had the answer, but I did not understand at first.